# mobx-react upgrade to version 5, no longer create an array as iterator

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Following script was working fine on mobx 3.5.1 and mobx-react 4.4.1

```
this.filters = observable.map();
this.charges = observable([]);
....
...

     this.filteredCharges = computed(() => this.charges.filter(
          charge => !this.filters.keys().some(
            columnName => charge[columnName].toString().toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.filters.get(columnName).toLowerCase()) === -1,
          ),
        ));
```

Just done the upgrade to mobx 5.6.0 and mobx-react 5.3.6

and start getting error

```
TypeError: _this.filters.keys(...).some is not a function
```

[image]

After reading this, it makes sense.

> All iterables no longer create an array as iterator, but only a real
>   iterator, to be more closely aligned to the official specs. So
>   previously observableMap.values() would return an array and iterator,
>   but now it will only return an iterator. So you can no longer do
>   observableMap.values().map(fn). Instead, use
>   Array.from(observableMap.values()).map(fn) or
>   mobx.values(observableMap).map(fn). The affected iterators are: 1. The
>   default iterator for observable arrays. 2. The default iterator for
>   observable maps. observableMap.entries(), observableMap.keys() and
>   observableMap.values().

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/wiki/Migrating-from-mobx-3-to-mobx-4

**Question is, how can I change above script efficiently to make it work with 
upgrade version of mobx.**

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there would be better way to fix it, this is one way of doing it.

```
 import { observable, computed, toJS } from 'mobx';

    this.filteredCharges = computed(() => this.charges
      .filter(charge => !Object.keys(toJS(this.filters))
        .some(columnName => charge[columnName].toString().toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(((typeof this.filters.get(columnName) === 'object') ?
            this.filters.get(columnName).value :
            this.filters.get(columnName)).toLowerCase()) === -1)));
```